# Al tocar en una imageView ( Kotlin) quiero conocer las coordenadas (x, y) del punto donde se tocó

Tags: kotlin

Al tocar en una imageView ( Kotlin)  quiero conocer las coordenadas (x, y) del punto donde se tocó.

muchas gracias.

Answer (score -1):

¿ya intentaste agregándole un evento de click a tu imageView?

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int[] values = new int[2]; 
        view.getLocationOnScreen(values);
        Log.d("X & Y",values[0]+" "+values[1]);
    }
});
```